# Use SP 2010 XLV web part to aggregate multiple lists

Tags: xlv, web-part

I have a site collection containing sites with the same list template called Tasks.  I want to aggregate all the active tasks and display them at the top level site.  I think the XSLT List View Web Part (XLV) is the solution because I'm not an expert at XSLT so I don't want to use a CQWP and apply XSLT if possible.  I believe that was the solution in SP 2007, but the new web part in SP 2010 is supposed to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/11/17/inconvenient-user-tasks-web-part-and-how-to-make-it-display-all-tasks/) by Waldek Mastykarz describes how you could achieve that with Content Query Web Part. It's seems to be perfect for your scenario.

In case you do not want to use Content Query Web Part, the alternative is to use Data View Web Part, check how you can [Add a linked data source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-linked-data-source-HA010115404.aspx) and [Display data from multiple datasources](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-data-view-HA010099144.aspx).

Comment: Close but not quite.  CQWP only brings back Title.  I want more columns than that.  I believe CQWP requires some XSL work to add columns. I don't want to do that.  I thought XLV web part provides administrative options to add columns without writing code.  The user task web part only shows open tasks for "current" user.  I want all users.  Thanks.

Comment: Made some changes, hope these will help. There is no wizard that will allow you to do this from UI, you need to use some XSLT or HTML to get it to work. For wizards you will have to use 3rd party tools like: http://www.lightningtools.com/lightning-conductor-2010-web-part.aspx